# What is stored in Inte's spi flash? Is it a BOIS?

Tags: memory, x86, eeprom

We have Intel's board (i7) with Linux, and we need to save some data between power off/on.
I thought of using the spi flash for this (there is also eeprom, but for some reason it is read-only!).

But I am not sure what is stored in spi flash.
Is it that the BIOS is saved in eeprom, and the spi flash can be used by application for any general purpose ? How can I know where is the bios saved ?

On using flashrom it seems that I can write to the flashrom, yet I am afraid that something important is already stored in the flash.

Does anyone knows what is stored in spi flash ?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-SPI-flash-memory is a start.  A number of Google links searching on "spi flash".